# Does keeping a pen in the wrong orientation gradually decrease the quality of ink?

Tags: home, stationery

- Ball point pens
- Unused

I like to buy pens from one certain brand (Montex Megatop; cheap good quality pen). I often buy 3-6 in advance and store them in the almirah. But I have noticed that for some pens either the ink becomes dry and thin after 2/3rds is used or it stops working completely.

- Could this be because of storing them for long time (3 weeks for each pen)?
- Could I prevent this by keeping them upside down?

Comment: Hi user764565, Welcome to Lifehacks. Have you contacted the manufacturer regarding best storage conditions and usable lifespan? Also, don't forget to have a peek at the Lifehacker site [Tour] and [Help] for tips on getting the best out of the site. You even get a badge for the accomplishment.

Comment: Perhaps it is just because those cheap pens are not as good as you think. From the question title, is it *only* the pens you have stored that run thin/dry or *any* of them. One other way you could look at it, is if the pens run out after 2/3 use, then they effectively cost you 50% more.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a neat insight. I will consider changing them now!

Comment: Perhaps keep them in the shop rather than the almirah, that way they stand a better chance of being fresh when you come to use them ;)

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! This isn't _quite_ a Lifehacks question, but you can make it into one. Currently, the subject is asking a yes-or-no-question. On Lifehacks, we ask questions that require creative solutions, like "How can I maintain the quality of ink in my ballpoint pens for the life of the pen?" Then you can write about some ideas you had, and ask for other people's suggestions. Please consider changing your question - you'll get more creative answers that way!

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane. Most offices I've worked in will buy a box of 100 ballpoint pens and they can sit there for a year with no ill-effects. If I look around and find a really old pen in the back of a drawer, it almost always works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you keep the pen upside down for a long time, they dry or ink flow is irregular. The gravitational pull is a reason, you can even try this with 'markers'. Sometimes the ball pens also dry off if they are not used regularly.